# AngularJS $injector:unpr issue

Tags: angularjs

im completely new to angularJS, below is the minimal example of my issue:

`myModule.module.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule', [
            'myServices',
            'myControllers'
        ]);

    angular
        .module('myServices', []);

    angular
        .module('myControllers', []);

})();
```

`myService.service.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .factory('myServices', myServices);

  function myServices() {
    var service = {};
    return service;
  }
})()
```

`myController.js`:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
    angular
        .module("myModule")
        .controller("myController", myController);

    myController.$inject = ['myServices']
    myController(myServices) {
      /* use myServices */
    }
})()
```

I think I accomplished all things needed to make service available to controller but I'm still getting unresolved provider error...

I'm coming from strong Angular2+ background and maybe some common potfall I'm unaware of? Does the tile names os services must match their angular name or something similar?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the definitions for `myServices` and `myControllers` come before the definition of `myModule`?

Comment: @DanieleTorino there are like 50 modules in this project that are created exactly same way and they work... I moved modules declarations up, with no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah, Angular2+ experience strikes on this one. Basically I was absolutely unaware about managing scripts in `main.html` (or whatever entry point for app is). So basically I was dumb enough not tu supply my `main.html` with specified script file.

So, assuming that my usecase was to add just another service to already working `myModule`, then

```
<script src="path/to/myService.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help someday some other dev lost in AngularJS :)

Cheers